# loop inside loop lodash

Tags: javascript, loops, lodash

I have an array how build like this:

```
"list": [
    {
        "insideList": [{"code": "0", "image": "./images/1"},
                    {"code": "1", "image": "./images/2"},
                    {"code": "2", "image": "./images/3"}],
        "bucket": "info",
        "instructions": "first set".\n",
        "color": "rgb(242, 242, 140)",
        "id": "a",
        "text": "first quest"
    },
   ...
```

I'm trying to flatten this list with lodash, but I dont know how to map inside map when the first map also do things.
that what i did for the outer loop:

```
var withIndex = _.map(list,(item, i) => ({

      [`iv_${i}_text`]: item.text,
      [`iv_${i}_instructions`]: item.instructions,
      [`iv_${i}_color`]: item.color,
      [`iv_${i}_id`]: item.id,
      [`iv_${i}_bucket`]: item.bucket,
    }));
```

but now i want to add the inside loop on 'aspects' list and build something like this:

```
 var withIndex = _.map(list,(item, i) => ({
  [`iv_${i}_text`]: item.text,
  [`iv_${i}_instructions`]: item.instructions,
  [`iv_${i}_color`]: item.color,
  [`iv_${i}_id`]: item.id,
  [`iv_${i}_bucket`]: item.bucket,
  [`iv_${i}_a_0_code`]: item.insideList[0].code,       
  [`iv_${i}_a_0_image`]: item.insideList[0].image,  
  [`iv_${i}_a_1_code`]: item.insideList[1].code,       
  [`iv_${i}_a_1_image`]: item.insideList[1].image,
  [`iv_${i}_a_2_code`]: item.insideList[2].code,       
  [`iv_${i}_a_2_image`]: item.insideList[2].image
}));
```

It is possible to do something like this using lodash?

```
var withIndex = _.map(list,(item, i) => ({
      [`iv_${i}_text`]: item.text,
      [`iv_${i}_instructions`]: item.instructions,
      [`iv_${i}_color`]: item.color,
      [`iv_${i}_id`]: item.id,
      [`iv_${i}_bucket`]: item.bucket,
```

and here do another map:

```
 _map(insideLoop, (item, j)=> ({
      [`iv_${i}_a_{j}_code`]: item.insideList[0].code,       
      [`iv_${i}_a_{j}_image`]: item.insideList[0].image,  
      [`iv_${i}_a_{j}_code`]: item.insideList[1].code,       
      [`iv_${i}_a_{j}_image`]: item.insideList[1].image,
      [`iv_${i}_a_{j}_code`]: item.insideList[2].code,       
      [`iv_${i}_a_{j}_image`]: item.insideList[2].image
    }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Reducing (accumulating) object properties should do the thing, then just merge both objects:

```
var withIndex = _.map(list, (item, i) => _.assign(
  {
    [`iv_${i}_text`]: item.text,
    [`iv_${i}_instructions`]: item.instructions,
    [`iv_${i}_color`]: item.color,
    [`iv_${i}_id`]: item.id,
    [`iv_${i}_bucket`]: item.bucket,
  },
  _.reduce(item.insideList, (acc, x, j) => {
    acc[`iv_${i}_a_${j}_code`]: x.code
    acc[`iv_${i}_a_${j}_image`]: x.image
    return acc
  }, {})
));
```

Also you don't need *lodash* after all (native functions are faster):

```
var withIndex = list.map((item, i) => Object.assign(
  {
    [`iv_${i}_text`]: item.text,
    [`iv_${i}_instructions`]: item.instructions,
    [`iv_${i}_color`]: item.color,
    [`iv_${i}_id`]: item.id,
    [`iv_${i}_bucket`]: item.bucket,
  },
  item.insideList.reduce((acc, x, j) => {
    acc[`iv_${i}_a_${j}_code`]: x.code
    acc[`iv_${i}_a_${j}_image`]: x.image
    return acc
  }, {})
));
```